After importing the project. Getting `>` in my spring boot project
i copied from one existing project and changed the artifact id and group id. After that i imported the project into the existing work space. On importing i can see
> symbol.
Please refer the screenshot attached and please advice.

And what exactly is the error? You don't like the > symbol? Or is there anything not working anymore but you're too scared to provide the error log? Please clarify your question, or better: Ask a question at all. [ask]
